# can we run java swing and applet on android

Tags: android

can we run java swing and applet on android

Answer (score 2):

No. Android has its own display framework.

Answer (score 1):

You can't run Swing on Android. Nor can you run Java Applets. Some aspects of Android's UI API are similar to Swing however.